# Verifying an optimization using lagrangian multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to find the extremes of $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ constrained by $x^2+y^2=1$

I'm thinking this must be a typo. Because then there is some $(x,y)$ such that $$\begin{cases} 2x=2\lambda x \\ -2y=2\lambda y \\ x^2+y^2=1 \end{cases}$$

substituting $x=\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$ into $2x=2\lambda x$ gave me $y=\pm \sqrt3/2$ and $x=\pm1/2$
but how do I verify analytically that these are the extreme values?

Answer (score 1):

By observation, the maxima will be at (1,0), (-1,0) and the minima at (0,1), (0,-1). Using the KKT conditions,

$\nabla f(\overline {\mathbf x}) + \sum u_i \nabla g_i(\overline {\mathbf x}) + \sum \lambda_i \nabla h(\overline {\mathbf x})=\mathbf 0$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ -2y \\ \end{bmatrix} + \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf 0$$

For $\overline {\mathbf x} = (1,0)$ and $(-1,0), \lambda = -1. $

For $\overline {\mathbf x} = (0,1)$ and $(0,-1), \lambda = 1. $

Finding the Hessian of the Lagrangian,

$$\nabla^2 L(\overline {\mathbf x}) =\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2(\lambda +1) & 0 \\ 0 & 2(\lambda -1) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix is positive semidefinite for $\lambda = 1$ and negative semidefinite for $\lambda = -1$, corresponding to minima and maxima, respectively.